# 2 of the same processes with different PIDs running - not threaded

Tags: process

This is not a multi-threaded process. With `ps` and `top` I observed:

```
[user@host]$ ps aux | grep -i [r]redacted                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
500       3073  6.1 11.7 1457148 188188 ?      Sl   Feb14  91:54 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/redacted_proc
500       3120  6.1 11.0 1541952 177184 ?      Sl   Feb14  91:56 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/redacted_proc


top - 10:02:55 up 728 days, 19:30,  3 users,  load average: 0.26, 0.14, 0.14
Tasks:  99 total,   1 running,  97 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.7%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.1%st
Mem:   1598640k total,  1239756k used,   358884k free,   192296k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   346756k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 3120 redacted  20   0 1505m 173m 4648 S 10.3 11.1  93:33.08 redacted_proc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 3073 redacted  20   0 1422m 185m 4608 S  6.6 11.9  93:31.04 redacted_proc
```

Since killing both PIDs and starting the process up normally, there again is a single running PID for this process.

What would cause Linux to run 2 of the same process like this, especially when it's init script should be accounting for that already, and a single entry under `/var/run/redacted.pid` only exists?

I am including the contents of the init script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

RETVAL=0
DAEMON=redacted_process
BIN="/usr/bin/redacted_process"
OPTS=""
RUNAS=redacted
PIDDIR=/var/run/${DAEMON}
PIDFILE=${PIDDIR}/${DAEMON}.pid

start () {
    echo -n "Starting ${DAEMON}: "
    [ -f ${PIDFILE} ] && success && echo && return 0
    su -s /bin/bash ${RUNAS} -c "
        cd /
        ${BIN} ${OPTS} &> /dev/null &
        echo \$! > ${PIDFILE}
        disown \$!
    "
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && success || failure
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}

stop () {
    echo -n "Shutting down ${DAEMON}: "
    killproc ${DAEMON}
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/${DAEMON}
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f ${PIDFILE}
    return $RETVAL
}

restart () {
    stop
    start
    RETVAL=$?
    return $RETVAL
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart|reload)
        restart
        ;;
    status)
        status ${DAEMON}
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: ${0} {start|stop|restart|status}"
        RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

This is interesting, there is also an entry in `/etc/crontab` for this job that runs every minute:

```
    /sbin/service redacted status > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" -gt "0" ]; then
        /bin/rm /var/run/redacted_proc/*
        /sbin/service redacted restart && tail -n 200 /var/log/redacted_proc/redacted_prod.log | mail -s "redacted pid restarted on ${HOSTNAME}" user@example.com
    fi
```

And `ps` for that cron job shows as `<defunct>`.

I am wondering if this somehow caused this program to get run twice.

Comment: Two of the same program (maybe), but not the same process (different pid).

Comment: Absolutely true - maybe this is where I am getting hung up. I think the init script might have the answer about this behavior.

Comment: Have a look at the output of the command `ps -ejf` which lists PPID and post the two relevant lines (plus headline) please.

Comment: Unfortunately as this is was in a production environment I had to kill the PIDs and start a new process to keep things moving. I may play with it in a test environment to see if I can replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something (or more than one thing) seems to have run that program twice.

try `ps ax -o ppid,pid,lstart,cmd` to get start time of processes. And search scripts that may have started it.

Also look at parent-process-id.

Comment: I have included the contents of the init script.